# Expandable row in table with flutter- is it possible?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm trying to achive a way to expaned the rows in a table, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

I would like to click on one of my rows in the table and make it extendable to show more data about the ROW, and then the second press will close it back to a the table.

i tried using the Expanded widget, but it didn't work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StagePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Table(
          defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.0),
          border: TableBorder.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 2),
          children: [
      TableRow( children: [
      Column(children:[Text('Website', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),
    Column(children:[Text('Tutorial', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),
    Column(children:[Text('Review', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),
    Card(
    child: ExpansionTile(
    title: Text(
    'Website',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
    children: <Widget>[
    Text('About Website'),
    Text('Add more data'),
    Text('add more more data'),
    // add more data that you want like this
    ],
    ),
    )],
      ),]
    )


    );
  }
}
```

any help or suggestions will be great! thank you!

this is the result of my code:
but i wanted to open the all row without the lines and the table borders.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [ExpansionPanelList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) widget or [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) dependency for that.

Comment: using expandable is the one I needed! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

wrap every widget that you need to expand with `Card` ,
and add an `ExpansionTile` inside a `Card`

example -

```
Card(
    child: ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(
        'Website',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('About Website'),
        Text('Add more data'),
        Text('add more more data'),
        // add more data that you want like this
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to warp every widget.
I tried using your code, but it expanded the table with all of the lines.
i added a image in the main post for you to see.

Comment: Glad to help you... Welcome and Happy coding :)